# Get suffix from a string as int

Tags: c#, string, integer

I've got a list containing file information on a remote server. The files on this server have a certain file name with a suffix that increments and is always 9 characters long:

- 20220123SOMENAME000000001
- 20220132SOMENAME000000002
- 20220201SOMENAME000030000
- 20220202SOMENAME000030002

I'm trying to create a method that takes the string above as input and returns an int (1, 2, 30000 and 30002) from the examples above.

```
public int GetCounterFromFileName(string fileName)
{
    // some logic extracting the index.

    int index = 0;

    return index;
}
```

Should I use regex to delete the prefix and infix and then get the index from the suffix?

Comment: Do *NOT use regex if not needed*. regex can be quite expensive (computation) because it's in general such a powerful matching-tool. In your case you only need a simple Substring to extract the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the last nine digits of the filename to integer by:

```
public int GetCounterFromFileName(string fileName)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(fileName[^9..]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use substring to cut out the last nine characters, and then parse them to an int:

```
public int GetCounterFromFileName(string fileName)
{
    return int.ParseInt(fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 9));
}
```

Comment: or, by using C# 8.0 [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes): `Int32.Parse(filename[^9..])`